# How to print text to printer in Python without having filename printed on first (or each pages)?

Tags: python, operating-system, temporary-files

```
import tempfile
import os 

q=tempfile.mktemp(".txt")
open(q,"w").write("the writing")
os.startfile(q,"print")
```

while running this code there is an output from the printer as [ "the writing" ] (it's ok) and
there is also a text called := " tempsh03uiuc.txt " at the top of the paper.
help me to solve this, " tempsh03uiuc.txt " is an irrelevant thing.

Comment: "tempsh03uiuc.txt" is the filename. It is printing that before printing the contents.

Comment: Hello kk, can you please change the title of your question because it is too general. Example: How to print text to printer in Python without having filename printed on first (or each pages) ? It would be interesting to print a text over more than 1 page to see if filename is printed only on first page or on each pages.

Comment: Use of `tempfile.mktemp()` has been [deprecated since version 2.3](https://docs.python.org/3/library/tempfile.html#deprecated-functions-and-variables): Use [`mkstemp()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/tempfile.html#tempfile.mkstemp) instead.

Comment: What OS are you using?

Comment: I'm using windows 10.

Comment: @Chris Yes, But I want to print the file without it.